# проверить, есть ли параметр "?" в url php

Tags: php

Как проверить есть ли "?" в url, не зная конкретного параметра

Comment: вы про произвольную URL, либо текущую URL запроса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$mystring = 'https://www.onlinestore.com?parameter=value';
$findme   = '?';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Заметьте, что используется ===.  Использование == не даст верного 
// результата, так как 'a' в нулевой позиции.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "Строка '$findme' не найдена в строке '$mystring1'";
} else {
    echo "Строка '$findme' найдена в строке '$mystring1'";
    echo " в позиции $pos";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант короче.

```
$url = "https:/google.com/asd/asd";
$search = "?";
if (strpos($url, $search) !== false) {
    echo 'Знак "'.$search.'" есть в данном url.';
}
```

Comment: Это такое же решение только значение не присвоено переменной. Этот вариант не является короче

Comment: @Alpha короче - означает использование меньшего количества строк в коде. Комментарий ни о чём.

Comment: тогда уже сразу так, чтобы строчку сэкономить `echo strpos('https://www.onlinestore.com?parameter=value', '?') ? 'ectb' : 'netu';`